# Tomcat taking more space then configured?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm running a `tomcat8` server with the following config:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-Xmx4g
-Xms2g
-server
```

Thus I'd expect the tomcat not taking more than 4 GB of RAM. Which is important for always having ram left for other applications.

Problem: currently my tomcat is running at:

```
systemctl status tomcat8:
Memory: 6.7G
```

How could this happen at all? Would I have to restart a tomcat say once a month to prevent excessive memory growth?

```
top - 13:23:57 up 159 days, 20:34,  2 users,  load average: 0.14, 0.05, 0.02
Tasks: 200 total,   1 running, 199 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8174980 total,   152976 free,  7078572 used,   943432 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4198396 total,  1780352 free,  2418044 used.   689044 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                         
 7993 tomcat8   20   0 12.264g 6.603g   9716 S   1.0 84.7 787:13.05 java
```

Answer (score 1):

-Xmx only sets the max java heap, not the jvm process max. There is plenty of native memory used for jit, off-heap buffers, etc...

Comment: So how can I then limit the max used memory, if possible at all?

Comment: @membersound You cannot.

Comment: Well if not, would it help limiting `-Xmx2g` to 2g?

Comment: I think so. Only one way to find out!